# HTMLAgilityPack Why are Attributes not correctly encoded after reading Utf-8 Encoded File

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, html-agility-pack

I am reading a HTML file that is utf-8 encoded:

```
htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.Load( filePath );
```

The file contains a valid `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag, and after loading, the `Encoding` property of `htmlDocument` is correctly set to `System.Text.Encoding.Utf8`.

However, if I read an attribute from a node:

```
        var node = document.GetElementbyId( id );
        var filename = node.Attributes["filename"].Value;
```

the string is not correct if the `filename` attribute contains non-ASCII characters.
I have to convert the encoding manually from UTF-8:

```
            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes( encodedString );
            var attr = document.Encoding.GetString( bytes );
```

Is this by design?
If the htmldocument's `Encoding` property is set to UTF-8, I would have expected that the attribute values would already be returned in the correct .Net standard encoding.

I am using HTMLAgilityPack version 1.8.4.

Comment: You say you have to convert "manually from UTF-8", but the following code is converting from Windows-1252. Have you made sure that the file `filePath` points to was actually saved in UTF-8?

Comment: @Xerillio: When I take a look at the html in Notepad++, everything looks fine, and Notepad++ tells me that the file is encoded in UTF-8. IN the conversion code, the first line is used to get the data byte by byte as it is saved in the file (and the string), and the second line is used to convert it from UTF-8 to a standard .Net string.
With this conversion, everything works well, I only wonder why I need it.

Comment: What happens if you do `htmlDocument.Load(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))` instead?

Comment: @Xerillio: Nothing changes. If I use `htmlDocument.Load(filePath, Encoding.UTF8)`, then everything is OK, but this way, the encoding is hardcoded and not taken from the HTML file. Theres an option named `OptionReadEncoding` but this also makes no difference.
I will stay with the hardcoded solution, which is fine for me. However, handling of encoding seems to be quite obsure with HtmlAgilityPack.